# Capturing real time images from a network camera

Tags: c++, camera, video-streaming, video-capture, mjpeg

What is the best way to capture streamed MJPEG from a network IP camera?

I'd like to get frames and process them, using c++ (or python extended with c++).

Is OpenCV my best option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appart from OpenCV, you can use mplayer with -vo yuv4mpeg redirected to a pipe to get a stream of uncompressed yuv images. You can create the mplayer process and pipe from C++.

Another way is to use a RTSP library (your IP camera probably uses it as protocol)

Comment: Actually OpenCV can use rtsp too, with cvCreateCaptureFromFile