# How to get a live snapshot from IP camera?

Tags: c++, windows, ip-camera

Has anyone ever managed to do this?

I'm totally out of clues now..

Comment: This is platform specific question, so you have to point out which OS do you use.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Capturing real time images from a network camera](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117042/capturing-real-time-images-from-a-network-camera)

Answer (score 0):

[Windows Image Acquisition (WIA)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms630368(VS.85).aspx)